# Is it possible to activate a squad-bonus enchanced ammo type without overriding squad members' settings?

Tags: mass-effect-3

If, for example, I get Shepard to activate Cryo Ammo (which has the +50% effectiveness for squad mates) then it replaces any ammo setting they my squad mates have active. If I then switch on one of their powers (which has the same squad bonus) then it overrides Shepard's ammo setting. The two ammo types become mutually exclusive.

This is a problem because it means only the person with the last ammo type activated has it at full effectiveness, and I can't diversify.

Except for the obvious of respec'ing and avoiding the squad bonuses (so each member has to manage their own ammo types, which is what I'll do if I really have to) is there any way to avoid overriding a squad mate's ammo setting when activating one on another member that has a squad bonus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one Squad Ammo power can be active at a time. You don't need to respec *everyone*, just respec the people who you would rather have using ammunition other than Squad Ammo.

But no, there's no other way around this.

Comment: Damn, thought that would be the case, so thanks for the confirmation. Oh well, guess I'll need to have a tweak of people's skill sets at some point...

Answer (score 0):

Since squad ammo only affects the weapon equipped at the time you can have all 3 members of your crew with a different ammo power. How this would work: this hypothetical crew would need to also have all 3 members with an ammo power, so let's take Garrus (AP) Vega (Incendiary) and Shepard could have any other, say Warp. Equip your main weapon on Shepard and activate the ammo type you want there, then switch weapons. Active the ammo type on Garrus with the weapon you want him to use, and then have him switch weapon. Lastly, have Vega active his ammo type on his primary weapon. Then have Shepard and Garrus both switch to their main weapon. The ammo power applied will be the type applied while it was equipped during all of those steps. By changing this around a little you can apply none native ammo powers to the whole crew, albeit at the -50% effectiveness penalty.