# Group-benefitting ammo overrides in Mass Effect 3

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-series

If a group member has, say, Armor-Piercing Ammo skill set to benefit the whole group at 50%, does this mean that it will override my own Armor-Piercing Ammo skill that is leveled to maximum and that I have to re-enable it, same as any other team member who wants to use Warp Ammo or Incendiary Ammo?

Or does the game know that my character's AP Ammo skill is superior to the group members and just enables that? The GUI isn't very helpful in that regard.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but really close that basically answers the question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54920/1134